# Security differences between Flex Application class and "normal" application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, security, sandbox

I have a problematic piece of code that uses Wordnik API to fetch word definitions. This code works fine in "local trusted" security sandbox, but doesn't work online - it produces a "security sandbox violation" (but no common ways of solving sandbox violation helped).

I've consulted this with Wordnik API creators and they didn't solve my problem directly but pointed me to a working example. Indeed their example works, but it uses Flex class "Application".

Same code that doesn't work in a standalone .as class, does work when used in Flex Application.

My question is: what are the differences (especially security differences) between Flex Application class and normal AS3 class extending Sprite?

I'm using Flashdevelop to compile. That can be important as Wordnik guys said that it worked fine in Flash Builder - although they didn't provide the details and I couldn't reproduce it.

I can attach the code if it is needed.

Comment: Attach code, please. Seems that you have problems with loading policy files.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not a policy problem. The same code works in Flex Application and doesn't work in "normal" application.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1FpEJMzZ "normal" code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3Urc5LNx Flex Application code.

Comment: The first thing I see - it is the difference in usage of wordnikClient.useProxyServer(...); Why it so?

Comment: Yes, this is a difference and it could be the THING :). But I checked it already and it didn't solve the problem. When UseProxyServes is set to false, application throws security sandbox violation errors (the same both in "normal" and in flex application). When it is set to true, the flex version works fine, while "normal" version doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I can't understand what is going on exactly, but I see what's happening - and seems, that it is not linked to flash security at all.

When you use mx app, WordnikClient sends serialized packets, that are different from non-mx app's packets:

mx app:

```
<object type="flex.messaging.messages.CommandMessage">
```

fl app:

```
<object>
```

And requests:

```
<object type="flex.messaging.messages.HTTPMessage">
```

vs

```
<object>
```

But when you are in local trusted sandbox, client uses GET requests, for example:

```
http://api.wordnik.com/v4/word.xml/drama/definitions?limit=1&useCanonical=true&api_key=148404f291e734bbf372b66b13785d85cb962394b22a8384e
```

Server returns xml.

So,

1) I can propose you to use just GET requests and parse XML ;). At least while this problem happening

2) Try to send this report to support. I think, that the problem can be in serialization process.

Hope it will help. Regards

Comment: Ooo, that's the kind of answer I was looking for! I'll pass it to Wordnik support guys, maybe they can help.

Comment: How do you check the raw contents of outgoing and incoming packages?

Comment: Usually, I use Fiddler2 (it has very powerful features for that stuff) or, when I need just read simple data, FireBug.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working using GET requests. I don't use Wordnik AS3 API at all :), but it does the job. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are always welcome. I didn't know about wordnik before your question, so it was interesting research. Please, set this question answered.